# Git: Cannot access url http://myserver/repo return code 56

Tags: git

I established Git Server on CentOS 5.5 with Curl 7.21.3. It works fine on CentOS (pull, push okay).

But when did git push from Windows, I always got an error:

> error: Cannot access URL http://myserver/repo/, return code 56
>   fatal: git-http-push failed

What does "return code 56" mean? How to fix it?

Comment: Which windows git client are you using (if any)?

Comment: Windows git client: msysgit, version: 1.7.9, download link: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

`code 56` is [CURLcode](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).

> CURLE_RECV_ERROR (56)
>   Failure with receiving network data.